# How to submit a SLURM job via sbatch that depends on a list of jobs

Tags: bash, slurm, sbatch

I have a shell script that submits multiple jobs to SLURM. These jobs are submitted within the following loop:

```
nb_partitions=72
slurmids=() # storage of slurm job ids
for k in $(seq 1 $nb_partitions); 
do
      cd results/partition$k/MainFolder
      ID=$(sbatch --parsable estimation.sh)
      slurmids+=($ID)
      cd ..
      cd ..
      cd ..
done
echo "Jobs are now running."
```

In addition to submitting the jobs, this loop also creates the array `slurmids` that contains a list of the job ids for all the SLURM jobs.

Now, I have another SLURM job that I would like to submit with `sbatch YY.sh`, but this job needs to wait to be submitted until **all** of the previous jobs finish. How can I do this? The command that comes to mind is `sbatch --dependency=afterok<jobID1:jobID2:...:jobID72> YY.sh`, I'm not sure how to use my `slurmids` list in the `afterok` statement.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--dependency` syntax is:

> afterok:job_id[:jobid...]

So you need your array separated by a colon. You could simply echo the whole list and replace the spaces by colons in your command:

```
sbatch --dependency=afterok:$(echo ${slurmids[*]} | tr ' ' :) YY.sh
```

If you just need the slurmids for that single purpose, you could concatenate them in your first script in this way:

```
[...]
slurmids=""
for k in $(seq 1 $nb_partitions); 
do
      cd results/partition$k/MainFolder
      slurmids="$slurmids:$(sbatch --parsable estimation.sh)"
[...]
```

This will result in the a `$slurmids` string with all the IDs separated with `:` and a leading `:`, so you could send:

```
sbatch --dependency=afterok$slurmids YY.sh
```

Comment: Great answer, this works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: No Problem! Can you mark this as the correct answer then?